# How to adjust node.js console log output?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, cheerio

So i have a script which outputs me answers in different lines like this:

```
 111.111
 111
 111.111
 111
```

And i want that output would look like this:

```
111.111:111
111.111:111
```

Its just putting every second line back and adding a : between them. I believe i need to change this part of my code:

```
$('#table, td').each(function(index,element) {
     if(index%8==1 || index%8==2){
           console.log($(this).text());
     }
});
```

Comment: node.js? Add the code of NodeJS, dont' use jQuery to do this.

Comment: in node.js use: process.stdout.write() instead of console.log(), or just use the console.log() for the newline

Comment: @tushar i use this in my node.js code and it works fine

Comment: I think you're confused about NodeJS and jQuery. Try: `var text = ''; $('#table, td').each(function(ind) { if (ind % 8 === 1) { text = $(this).text(); } else if (ind % 8 === 2) { console.log(text + ':' + $(this).text()); text = ''; }});`

Comment: @Tushar it's not jQuery in client ... it's cheerio in node

Comment: Where does the regex and cheerio come from?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the info. It looks like jQuery, and I didn't notice the tag. But my above code should work.

Comment: loop over rows instead of cells then combine the text needed on each row

Comment: @tushar thank you bro it works like i wanted :D

Comment: If you're scraping specific columns of a table, you should probably start by selecting `<tr>`s, then inside that loop pick the `<td>` rows you want rather than going directly to `<td>`s. `#table, td` is an odd selector, iterating tables and their cells in the same loop. But hard to say without the HTML, and I know this is an old (unanswered) post.